# How to revert button text if error message is triggered on checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

Why won't this code revert the button text back to Place Order if an error message is triggered?

The text was changed upon clicking the button, which works fine.
But it should change back if an error message occurs upon clicking the button.
There are no console messages for the error.
This is a Stripe payment button, it's Woocommerce.

```
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
        function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
          if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
        ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery( function($){
              jQuery('form.checkout').on('submit', function(event) {
                jQuery('button#place_order').text('Please Wait');
                event.preventDefault();
              });
          });
    
         //To detect woocommerce error trigger JS event
          jQuery( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
                    var wooError = $('.woocommerce-error');
                    jQuery('button#place_order').text('Place Order');
            } );

</script>
 <?php
  endif;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error(s) in the console? If so, please include the full error/warning message in your question!

Comment: This is what I get in the console: https://i.imgur.com/cZtHrxv.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. just replace `$('.woocommerce-error')` with `jQuery('.woocommerce-error')`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
    function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
        if ( is_checkout() ) :
                ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  jQuery( function($){
                      jQuery('.checkout').on('submit', function(event) {
                        jQuery('button#place_order').text('Please Wait');
                        event.preventDefault();
                      });
                  });
            
                 //To detect woocommerce error trigger JS event
                  jQuery( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
                            var wooError = jQuery('.woocommerce-error');
                            jQuery('button#place_order').text('Place Order');
                    } );

        </script>
        <?php
        endif;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Vel, I will try it as soon as my site will be back online. Thanks!